# Is it important to do code signing?

Tags: exe, code-signing, authenticode

We would like to distribute our new windows software on the internet (exe file).

What are the benefits of getting an authenticode code signing certificate?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enroll in the Windows Error Reporting process and get crash reports, which is nice. Having your executable signed (and/or your installer) will prevent some of the "untrusted code" warnings that can be scary for users, and reduce the odds that you'll trip Microsoft's "this may be dangerous" checks.